# Is there a script I can use to create a folder, and move the files with the same name into it?

Tags: bash, rename

I have a large folder of rom files that I would like to convert into another file format.
I'm not able to just throw the entire folder and have it work.

So, I would need to create a folder based on the title of the rom, and then move all the files with the same title in either `.cue` or `.bin` into that folder to be able to convert them to a `.chd` file format.

```
TITLE (REGION).file or TITLE (REGION) (TRACK #).file
```

Example

```
'WWF Attitude (USA).cue'
'WWF Attitude (USA) (Track 1).bin'
'WWF Attitude (USA) (Track 2).bin'
'WWF Attitude (USA) (Track 3).bin'
'WWF Attitude (USA) (Track 4).bin'
'WWF Attitude (USA) (Track 5).bin'
'WWF Royal Rumble (USA).cue'
'WWF Royal Rumble (USA) (Track 1).bin'
'WWF Royal Rumble (USA) (Track 2).bin'
'WWF Royal Rumble (USA) (Track 3).bin'
```

I tried last night to F2 and copy name, create folder and move the files into there, but that is just a real pain.

After I am able to convert them to `.chd`, I would like to also get the completed file, and move it back to the starting directory that it was in

I.e.

```
dc/TITLE (REGION).file -> dc/TITLE/TITLE (REGION).file
dc/TITLE/TITLE (REGION).file -> dc/TITLE (REGION).convertedFile
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are *"roms"* please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell files!

Answer (score 1):

I usually do things like this with [bash parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).

```
root@c2869e4a99bb:/temp# tree
.
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 1).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 2).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 3).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 4).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 5).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA).cue
|-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 1).bin
|-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 2).bin
|-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 3).bin
`-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA).cue

0 directories, 10 files
root@c2869e4a99bb:/temp# for CUE in *.cue ; do TITLE="${CUE%.cue}" ; mkdir "${TITLE}" ; cp "${TITLE}"* "${TITLE}"/ ; done ;
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'WWF Attitude (USA)'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'WWF Royal Rumble (USA)'
root@c2869e4a99bb:/temp# tree
.
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)
|   |-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 1).bin
|   |-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 2).bin
|   |-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 3).bin
|   |-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 4).bin
|   |-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 5).bin
|   `-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA).cue
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 1).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 2).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 3).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 4).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA)\ (Track\ 5).bin
|-- WWF\ Attitude\ (USA).cue
|-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)
|   |-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 1).bin
|   |-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 2).bin
|   |-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 3).bin
|   `-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA).cue
|-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 1).bin
|-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 2).bin
|-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA)\ (Track\ 3).bin
`-- WWF\ Royal\ Rumble\ (USA).cue

2 directories, 20 files
```